Importing Tensorflow ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2
After installing tensorflow, i tried importing it for use and got an error
On my jupyterlab, i tried:
!pip install tensorflow

then:
 import tensorflow as tf

and was getting an error. What should i do?:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Hi @Owen , Could you please let us know in which OS you are facing this issue.Also can you try uninstalling Tensorflow and then reinstalling and please follow this link to install tensorflow.
